# Take control over Grails .war web.xml

Tags: grails, web.xml

I created the web.xml file using the create-templates command. After I finished editing the file, I run war command, in the war file I find a web.xml not the same one that I created previously, and it contains the following tags: `<filter-name>urlMapping</filter-name>` and

```
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>urlMapping</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Do you know how to disable those tags to be included automatically in the web.xml when I use the war command? (I don't want to edit manually the web.xml under the. War file)
What config files should I edit to do so?

Comment: Have you installed the webxml plugin? http://grails.org/plugin/webxml

Comment: nope :), it is used to customize the web.xml found in the war file ?

Comment: Yes. Check the [example](https://github.com/burtbeckwith/grails-webxml/blob/master/src/samples/_WebXmlConfig.groovy)